# Open-source serverless instant messenger for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, chat, mobile

I am looking for an instant messenger for android and ios that is open-source and serverless.

Comment: I'm not using such, but look for [clients using the Tox protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tox_(protocol)#Clients).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this, I will be able to use this!

Comment: Gladly! If you found a match for you, please consider to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Izzy the [Tox protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tox_(protocol)#Clients) is the solution. This is essentially a protocol that hits all my requirements by being peer-to-peer, open-source, and with end-to-end encryption. There are various clients using this protocol for the most important platforms.